# Polymer 3.0 a11ySuite testing error

Tags: testing, polymer, accessibility, polymer-3.x

I am trying to get `a11ySuite` in Polymer 3.0 tests to work.

When I am running the test with `polymer test`, the tests times out, and I can see in the console of the automated browser the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
at Suite.a11ySuite.eachTest (a11ySuite.js:51)
at mocha.js:1550
at Object.exports.forEach (mocha.js:1595)
at Suite.eachTest (mocha.js:1550)
at Runner.grepTotal (mocha.js:1224)
at Runner.grep (mocha.js:1215)
at new Runner (mocha.js:1197)
at Mocha.run (mocha.js:592)
at _runMocha (extend.js:41)
at done (util.js:34)
```

If I am running in debug mode, from `polymer serve` url, I am getting this error:

```
a11ySuite.js:49 Uncaught TypeError: fixtureElement.create is not a function
at Suite.a11ySuite.eachTest (a11ySuite.js:49)
at mocha.js:1550
at Object.exports.forEach (mocha.js:1595)
at Suite.eachTest (mocha.js:1550)
at Runner.grepTotal (mocha.js:1224)
at Runner.grep (mocha.js:1215)
at new Runner (mocha.js:1197)
at Mocha.run (mocha.js:592)
at _runMocha (extend.js:41)
at done (util.js:34)
```

This is also preceded by a bunch of 404 coming from mocha, regarding lodash, sinonjs and test-fixture, assuming this is because it is ran in `serve` mode.

This is my test code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Verifier - a11y test</title>

    <script src="../node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/web-component-tester/browser.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="../src/verifier.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <test-fixture id="BUVA11y">
        <template>
            <verifier id="verifier"></verifier>
        </template>
    </test-fixture>

    <script>
      suite('A11y testing', function() {
        a11ySuite('BUVA11y');
      });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I can't find more information online, and the docs are very limited on this subject (actually not precise indeed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a11ySuite` was moved to `wct-browser-legacy` as of `web-component-tester` version [6.4.3](https://github.com/Polymer/web-component-tester/blob/e4ebc8066/CHANGELOG.md#643---2018-01-11). Given the "legacy" naming, I'm guessing it's deprecated. I assume it's used like this:

```
<script type="module">
  import {a11ySuite} from 'wct-browser-legacy/a11ySuite.js';
  a11ySuite('view1'); // "view1" == template name
</script>
```

But I could not get it to work in an otherwise clean `polymer-3-starter-kit` project (i.e., the `a11ySuite` property exists in the module but is always `undefined`). Setting up a breakpoint [where that variable is defined](https://github.com/Polymer/web-component-tester/blob/master/wct-browser-legacy/a11ySuite.js#L39), I can see that the variable is actually never set because the Mocha `pre-require` event handler is never invoked for whatever reason.

However, it appears that [`axe-core`](https://github.com/dequelabs/axe-core) (via [`pwa-helpers`](https://github.com/Polymer/pwa-helpers#axe-reportjs])) is the newest *a11y* testing tool to use in Polymer 3, based on the [test code in `pwa-starter-kit`](https://github.com/Polymer/pwa-starter-kit/blob/master/test/unit/views-a11y.html#L63):

```
<script type="module">
  import 'axe-core/axe.min.js';
  import {axeReport} from 'pwa-helpers/axe-report.js';

  suite('views a11y tests', function() {
    test('my-view1', function() {
      const el = fixture('view1');
      return axeReport(el);
    });
    ...
  });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I will try to open another PR on the docs to update that. I did _waste_ too much time on setting up that, because of the lack of information :(

Comment: @Moustachiste No problem :)